# Java code wont display dialogue boxes on my computer (OSX, J GRasp)

Tags: java, macos, io, dialog, user-input

Just joined the Stackoverflow to ask this question but i anticipate asking many more and eventually contributing.

Below is a code i wrote to display your personal "lucky lotto numbers"

```
// CS 1400
// Homework 2 




import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
public class Homework2 
{
public static void main( String[] arg)
{
JOptionPane box = new JOptionPane();
box.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill out the following dialog boxes to see 
your lucky lotto numbers."); 

String firstNumber = 
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter lucky/favorite number");
String secondNumber =
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the last two digits of your 
birth year");
String thirdNumber = 
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how many people are in your 
immediate family");
String fourthNumber =
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the last two digits of your 
mothers birth year");
String fifthNumber = 
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of your favorite 
star wars film");
String sixthNumber = 
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the jersey number of your 
favorite athlete");
String seventhNumber = 
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter lucky/favorite number 
again");

  int number1 = Integer.parseInt( firstNumber);
  int number2 = Integer.parseInt( secondNumber);
  int number3 = Integer.parseInt( thirdNumber);
  int number4 = Integer.parseInt( fourthNumber);
  int number5 = Integer.parseInt( fifthNumber);
  int number6 = Integer.parseInt( sixthNumber);
  int number7 = Integer.parseInt( seventhNumber);

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Here are your lucky lotto numbers!" + 
                                number4 +
                                number2 +
                                number7 +
                                number1 +
                                number5 +
                                number3 +
                                number6 );
    }
  }
```

The code actually seems to work but i cannot get my computer(Macpro) to display the dialogue boxes after Jgrasp runs the code. Which is the whole point of the exercise, I can send the Java file to my professor and hope it works... but i'd rather get another opinion.

My intention is to:

1. have a window appear instructing the user to fill out the dialogue boxes
2. take the user inputs
3. display the user inputs (in a new order) in a vertical line in a new dialogue box that the user can close out of to end the program.

Am i doing this right at all? again, Jgrasp seems to like what i've input but the dialogue boxes dont appear so i'm kinda confused.

Thanks for reading and responding

Comment: Does your code compile without errors? Does it run without exceptions?

Comment: I ask because the code you've posted shows illegal line breaks, and I don't know if this is an artifact of a bad posting of code, or if it is the way your code really looks.

Comment: After correcting your code formatting, it runs fine on my Mac

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks a bunch. 

are the illegal line breaks you're referring to .."



    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Here are your lucky lotto numbers!" + 
                                number4 +
                                number2 +
                                number7 +
                                number1 +
                                number5 +
                                number3 +
                                number6 );  "



Ones right here? ^ 

this is exactly what i have inputted to Jgrasp.

Comment: ***again*** are you getting any error messages? Please answer.

Comment: No I am not. sorry! @HovercraftFullOfEels